# R, data.table: How to assign values of some columns based on the names of other columns, which are stored in a character vector?

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data table:

```
dt=data.table(a=seq(1,3),b=letters[seq(1,3)],
          c=seq(4,6),d=letters[seq(4,6)])
dt
   a b c d
1: 1 a 4 d
2: 2 b 5 e
3: 3 c 6 f
```

I store the names of some columns in one vector and the names of other columns in another vector:

```
names1=names(dt)[1:2]
names2=names(dt)[3:4]
```

I need to assign the values of the columns stored in names2 to the columns of names1 when some conditions apply. Something like

```
dt[c(2,3),names1:=names2]

dt
   a b c d
1: 1 a 4 d
2: 5 e 5 e
3: 6 f 6 f
```

I have tried the following syntax without success:

```
dt[c(2,3),names1:=dt[c(2,3),names2,with=F]]
```

But it still tries to assign the values of the string vectors contained in names2

Comment: So the conditions are ... being in rows 2 or 3?

Comment: Well actually I'm using is.na(variable) in my specific case, but I think it is not so important for the means of this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would do

```
dt[2:3, (names1) := .SD, .SDcols = names2]
```

Or an alternative approach, thanks to @DavidArenburg:

```
dt[c(2,3), (names1) := mget(names2)]
```

*How it works*

- As @DavidArenburg explained, the parentheses in `(names1) :=` ensure that we look at the content of the `names1` vector instead of making a column named `"names1"`.
- I'd suggest going through [the first vignette for the package](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) for details on `.SDcols`.
- `mget` finds objects based on their names and puts them into a list.

Comment: You could probably add `dt[2:3, (names1) := mget(names2)]` as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can do this using with=F, is it inefficient in some way?.

The way I found it was like this:

```
dt[c(2,3),names1:=dt[c(2,3),names2,with=F],with=F]
```

Any comments on the efficiency would be nicely received.

Thank you.

Comment: Are we talking `dt[c(2,3), (names1) := mget(names2)]`? Not sure what's the desired output here.

Comment: Yes David!... I think this a much cleaner version, could you please tell me two things:

1. why the () in the LHS of :=?
2. mget() get the values of the variable names specified by strings?, is that it's purpose?. 

thank you again!, please post as answer and I will choose it.

Comment: The `()` wrapper is for `data.table` to understand you want the actual column names rather just some character string. And `mget` just gets the variables with these column names out of the parent environment. I think @Frank has even a better solution though.

Comment: Actually I can't find Frank's solution... where did you find it?

Comment: He posted it somewhere else- but maybe he will posted here too? @Frank

Comment: Ok, I'd do `dt[2:3, (names1) := .SD, .SDcols = names2]`. I think it's more idiomatic.